Can't get variable assigned in Bash case statement
I need to be able to use a variable value that's assigned in a bash case statement.
My input file has a single line.
30.xx.xx.xx,Bill

Here's my code
#!/bin/bash

MyList=IPlist.csv


while IFS=, read -r myIP UserName _
do

case $UserName in
  Tom)
      echo "Case is Tom and the IP address is $myIP..."
      UserName="Tom"
      echo "Username is $UserName"
      ;;
  Bill)
     echo "Case is Bill and the IP address is $myIP..."
     UserName="Bill"
     echo "Username is $UserName"
     ;;
  *)
     echo "Case is incorrect..."
     echo "Exiting line read...."
esac
done <$MyList
echo "$UserName"

This is the output I want
Tom@hostname ~
$ ./MyTest3.sh
Case is Bill and the IP address is 30.xx.xx.xx...
Username is Bill
Bill

Here's the output I'm getting
Tom@hostname ~
$ ./MyTest3.sh
Case is Bill and the IP address is 30.xx.xx.xx...
Username is Bill

I've been searching for the past hour and everything I find describes the code as I have it.
I even checked shellcheck and it says "No errors detected!"
Thanks in advance for any help.
Edit - 5-11-24
I forgot to mention that his is a test of case.
Ultimately I need read an 16,000 line comma delimited file and based on the username do snmpget to the devices to get the snmpv3 engineID.
In case that makes any difference to the method used in the case statement.

Are you sure your input file doesn't have a second, empty line? What's the output if you change the last line to something like echo "Last name was $UserName"?

Also, DOS line endings in your input file could cause UserName to be assigned an empty value on the second iteration, but skip the body of the loop altogether, so that your case statement never triggers the * case.

Are you reporting the full output you get?  Because if you had a trailing empty line then I would expect some additional output related to that.  ("Case is incorrect...", "Exiting line read....").

You loop will end when read will fail setting your variable. You have to break your loop when variable is set : UserName="Tom"; break.

The single line in the input file ends with a newline. Therefore, read tries to read the following line, too, but finds the EOF. When it tries to read the line, though, it clears all the variables it should populate.
Solution: Don't use the same variable for input and result.
#!/bin/bash

MyList=IPlist.csv

while IFS=, read -r myIP UserIn _
do
    case $UserIn in
        Tom)
            echo "Case is Tom and the IP address is $myIP..."
            UserName="Tom"
            echo "Username is $UserName"
            ;;
        Bill)
            echo "Case is Bill and the IP address is $myIP..."
            UserName="Bill"
            echo "Username is $UserName"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Case is incorrect..."
            echo "Exiting line read...."
    esac
done <$MyList
echo "$UserName"

To debug the issue, I used set -xv at the start of the script. It showed me which lines were executing and what values were assigned to variables.

I used set -xv a lot years ago writing nsh scripts for BladeLogic. Can't believe I forgot about it.

Odd.  When I test with an input file that has a trailing empty line, I get (as I expected) additional output pertaining to that line, which is not reflected in the output reported by the OP.

Yes, but  while read -r User;do  case $User in Tom|Bill) echo $user ; break; *) echo user unknow...;;esac;done <file; echo $user  is another solution shorter as you don't need to read whole file once username is found...

Or you can change code like this:
#!/bin/bash

MyList=IPlist.csv

while IFS=, read -ra line
do
    myIP=${line[0]}
    UserName=${line[1]}
    case $UserName in
      Tom)
          echo "Case is Tom and the IP address is $myIP..."
          echo "Username is $UserName"
          ;;
      Bill)
         echo "Case is Bill and the IP address is $myIP..."
         echo "Username is $UserName"
         ;;
      *)
         echo "Case is incorrect..."
         echo "Exiting line read...."
    esac

done <$MyList
echo "$UserName"

I'll save myIP and UserName from rewrite:
Case is Bill and the IP address is 30.xx.xx.xx...
Username is Bill
Case is Tom and the IP address is 30.xx.xx.xx...
Username is Tom
Case is incorrect...
Exiting line read....
John

It's an algorithmic problem, it could be illustrated simpler like this:
$ cat -A f
one$
two$

while read line; do
    echo $line
done < f

echo "Last value: $line"

Expected output is:
one
two
Last value: two

But actual output is:
one
two
Last value:

Because $line is renewed by read and at the end it's just empty. while read it's a processor so you have to process the data on the fly and if you need to save something it should be saved somewhere else, to a different variable or to an array.
while read line; do
    echo $line
    last=$line
done < f

echo "Last value: $last"
one
two
Last value: two

